# Eclipse unable to find the css file for GWT binder

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse, gwt

I am using UI binder for my GWT UI file and I am providing the relative path to load the css file which present in other directory but eclipse is showing the file is missing. Could you please help me how to fix that issue.

`<ui:style src="../../../../public/css/sample.css"/>`

Location of Ui file 
`project/src/main/java/com/sample/gwt/client/a/b/c/d/view/e/f.ui.xml`

Location of css file
`project/src/main/java/com/sample/gwt/client/a/b/public/css/sample.css`

I can see the css file at that location but eclipse is unable to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

We often have caching problems with eclipse. The usual workaround is:

Double-click on the generated .java file to open it and press F5 if the file is out of sync.

If it doesn't work clear the gwtUnitCache folder.

And if it doesn't work clear the rest of the target folder.